# "connection reset by peer" on google but not aws to exact same site

Tags: python, ssl, networking, amazon-ec2, google-compute-engine

I have the following code below, running on my AWS EC2 server as well as my Google Cloud (GCP) Compute Engine as a test. (I need to decommission EC2 for Google)

Telnet works from  both AWS and GCP, but when I try connecting:

- AWS is successful (Gets data)
- GCP fails with "Connection Reset by peer"

The code that is being run for the test is:

```
import requests, json
import datetime as dt

epoch_date = int((dt.datetime(2018,2,21) - dt.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())
url = 'https://www.zacks.com/includes/classes/z2_class_calendarfunctions_data.php?calltype=eventscal&date={}&type=1'.format(epoch_date)
req = requests.get(url)
data = req.text
print(data[0:100])
```

The exception I get on GCP is: (AWS Left, Google Right)

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 376, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 610, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 247, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/home/karunkrishna/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 692, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 560, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 379, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1197, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 575, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 929, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 791, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 575, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

I wonder if this is pointing to a SSL/Handshake issue on google server. But I don't know how to fix this. Not sure why Zacks.com would limit Google IP, but not AWS IP. Firewalls are enabled for both AWS and GCP. Any thoughts on how I can fix this? Or What else I should explore?

Comment: *"I wonder if this is pointing to a SSL/Handshake issue on google server"* - Given that it aborts while reading the response it must have sent the request successfully which means that the SSL handshake (which comes before sending the request) was also done successfully.

Comment: How do you know zacks.com has sent a response? So is the issue that GCP is rejecting the response, and as a result my python is not getting the json response?

Comment: *"How do you know zacks.com has sent a response?"* - I'm not claiming that zacks.com has sent a (HTTP) response. I'm saying that the TLS handshake was successful. I got this conclusion since the code is in `conn.getresponse`, i.e. it is trying to read the HTTP response. Since the HTTP response is read after the request has been send it must have been send the request. And since the request is sent only after the SSL handshake has been successful.

Comment: It might be that the HTTP request send by the client is different between between AWS and GCP due to a different version of Python and requests and that the server likes the one from AWS but not the other. It might also that the server blocks requests from GCP for some reason. Unfortunately I have no way to reproduce what you see so I cannot debug it further and can only guess what might be the case.